# Infinite scrolling in ReactJS from scratch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, infinite-scroll

I should create an infinite scroll in reactJs having a JSON with data in it. Could you help me?

I would like to do it from scratch and not with some library

```
{data?.map((conto) => {

  return (
    <Suspense key={conto._uid} fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <Conto blok={conto} data={data} ITEuro={ITEuro} deposit={deposit} handleToggleFavourite={handleToggleFavourite} isFavourited={isFavourited} depositQuantity={depositQuantity} />
    </Suspense>
  )

})}
```

I load the JSON like this for now, but I would like a maximum number of ids to be loaded until we reach the bottom of the page and more are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it this way

```
export default function App() {
  const [limiteData, setLimiteData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
     setIsLoading(true);

     // Simula un ritardo di caricamento per mostrare l'indicatore di caricamento
     setTimeout(() => {
       const newData = data.slice((page - 1) * 5, page * 5); // Carica 10 elementi per pagina
       setLimiteData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...newData]);
       setPage((prevPage) => prevPage + 1);
       setIsLoading(false);
     }, 1000);
  }, [page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {limiteData.map((blok) => {
        return (
          <div key={blok._uid}>
            <h1>{blok.name}</h1>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
       </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).